# netbeans и php 7

Tags: php

Есть ли в netbeans поддержка php 7+ (в настройках указана только 5 версия php)?

Comment: Свежая версия `NetBeans` поддерживает `PHP 7`

Comment: Просто как раз в 8.2 в настройках стоит 5 версия

Comment: В каких настройках? у меня показывает `7.0` https://i.imgur.com/4rPMoFd.png

Comment: Сервис->Параметры->PHP и там стоит PHP 5

Comment: Так укажите путь к `PHP 7` :< Вообще интерпретатор для каждого проекта, вроде как, можно указывать индивидуально.

Comment: у меня указан на 7.2, но пишет 5

Comment: `Сервис->Параметры->PHP` - тут пишет `PHP интерпретатор 5`? ну пусть пишет, он не определяет версию, это просто, видимо, еще не сделали систему для поддержки 5 и 7 одновременно, поэтому еще не трогали. Либо просто забыли указать что не ниже 5ой версии.

Comment: я и имею ввиду, что уже указан путь и все определило, но пишет 5

Comment: `NetBeans` ничего не определяет -.- просто `указали путь - сохранили - забыли`